# Sublimetext custom key binding to Apple "cmd" button?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, key-bindings

What is the keyword to specify the "command" button for mac?

I want to be able to press "command+t" to open a new tab, for instance.

What do I type into the keybindings file?

This doesn't work.
[
    { "keys": ["command+t"], "command": "new_tab" },
]

Answer (score 6):

The proper key designation for the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key in OS X as well as the Windows key on other keyboards is `super`. So,

```
[ { "keys": ["super+t"], "command": "new_tab" }, ]
```

would be your key binding.

You can find the key binding reference [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html).